# php doesn't execute the query of mysql, but in mysql it's executable

Tags: php, mysql

everybody
i have a problem in my php program and I don't understand where is a problem.
When I execute first query everything is ok, but the second doesn't work. I tried to put in mysql I didn't reach the problem, then I thought that I have a problem with a variables and I changed them. But still nothing...
Could you please help me?...

```
//duplicate ressource 
        mysql_query("insert into ressource (id_mission, name, ressource_path, assignment, position)"
        ."select ".$new_id_mis.", name, ressource_path, assignment, position from ressource where id_mission=".$id_mission.";");
        /*testing in sql:
            insert into ressource (id_mission, name, ressource_path, assignment, position)
            select 70, name, ressource_path, assignment, position from ressource where id_mission=5;    */

        //duplicate report_part    NB: report_part.procedure => procedure is a key word in sql
        mysql_query("insert into report_part (id_mission, position, title, text, drawing, dataset, report_part.procedure, assignment)"
        ."select ".$new_id_mis.", position, title, text, drawing, dataset, report_part.procedure, assignment from report_part"
        ."where id_mission=".$id_mission.";");
        /*tested:
            insert into report_part (id_mission, position, title, text, drawing, dataset, report_part.procedure, assignment)
            select 17, position, title, text, drawing, dataset, report_part.procedure, assignment from report_part
            where id_mission=1;        */
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Check the return value of `mysql_query()`. If it returns false, print `mysql_error()` to see the reason for the error.

Comment: @developerCK There's no `values()` if you're inserting the result of a `select`. This is a standard SQL feature.

Comment: none, php doesn't execute, and he doesn't give me any warnings. When I verify in the data base I can't find the result of the second query

Comment: Errors from `mysql_query()` are not printed automatically. You have to do what I said: `echo mysql_error()`.

Comment: he gives nothing. that means I don't have any error or I didn't place it right?

Comment: Don't end your query with `;`.

Comment: is it possible you have two multiple connections in the same script, or after all includes, multiple connections? If so, they need to be given a TRUE parameter during connection creation. also, any usage of mysql_ commands should contain the desired connection on which you perform the command...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this should help:

```
$strQry = "INSERT INTO resource (id_mission, name, ressource_path, assignment, position) 
SELECT ".$new_id_mis.", name, ressource_path, assignment, position 
FROM resource WHERE id_mission=".$id_mission;

mysql_query($strQry);
```